Atención con las cuentas repetidas
Se está dando el caso de cuentas creadas con una diferencia de un día y con nombres iguales o similares. Está claro que la intención es vandalizar el sitio. Atención a estas cuentas y por favor, no responder, en su lugar utilizar el flag.
Más información en esta respuesta.
Voy a crear un logo que diga "colabora con la salud de SpanishSE" 



Relacionado: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405111/repeated-new-accounts/405226#405226  Me parecen especialmente relevantes el comentario de Terdón y las respuestas de Mari-Lou A Слава Україні y de Glofindel (moderador de SLE)

Ya... La pregunta de MetaSE es mía
